# Hiding Bootstrap Popover on buttonclick after hiding it with clicking outside popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a table on my webpage, and I have a cell with max-width 400px. I hide the overflow text, and upon clicking on it I use a bootstrap (3.3.6) popover to show the full text.

What I want is to dismiss the popover on the next click. If I click on the text, the popover appears. I click on the text again, it disappears.

But if I "close" the popover with clicking anywhere else on the screen, and then I "reopen" the popover and try to close it with clicking on the text again, it doesn't disappear.

Basically:

- click on text  -> popover appears
- click on text again -> popover disappears
- click on text -> popover appears
- click somewhere else, not on the text -> popover disappears
- click on text  -> popover appers
- click on text again -> popover does not disappear

My CSS:

```
.td-review {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 400px;
max-width : 400px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;}
```

My HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-middle" colspan="2">
                <div tabindex="0" class="td-review" role="button" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover"
                     data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" data-animation="true"
                     data-content="I'm a popover">
                    long long long text...
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>"
```

My Javascript:

```
$(function () {
$('html').on('click', function (e) {

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(e.target)
            && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
        else {
            $(this).popover('toggle');
        }
    });

    $('.popover').css('display', 'none');
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $('.popover').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
});});
```

Thanks for your help!